# Import wsdl file into C# WCF project, and expose wsdl contracts

Tags: c#, wcf, soap, wsdl

I have a wsdl file provided by third-party, and i need to use it as-is and expose the contracts in this wsdl to be consumed.

My problem is that my project has its own namespace, and this wsdl comes with a different namespace, and i have no idea how to get the job done.

Appreciate any help

**EDIT**

The third-party (gov) expect to call the service with their namespace

Example:
I have a *WCF Service Application* with namespace: `local.namespace`

**WSDL:**

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:ns0="http://com.gov.update.ws" targetNamespace="http://com.gov.update.ws">
    <wsdl:message name="updateStatus">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="xsns:updateStatus" xmlns:xsns="http://com.gov.update.ws"/>
    </wsdl:message>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

**Received SOAP:**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <ctx:clientContext xmlns:ctx="http://ClientContext">
         <ctx:clientUserId>123456</ctx:clientUserId>
      </ctx:clientContext>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <p820:updateStatus xmlns:p820="http://com.gov.update.ws">
         <transactionId>123456</transactionId>
         <status>Accepted</status>
      </p820:updateStatus>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: are you using svcutil or wsdl.exe to extract the contracts?

Comment: I'm not even sure which one to use! I used the svcutil, which produced an ugly file containing all [XML] decorations for (interfaces, namespace, and methods). Although I don't like the generated file, i still don't know how to use it as-is for the third-party to consume it

Answer (score 0):

In general, it is relatively common that we use the client proxy class to call the web service by adding service reference. As follows.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/accessing-services-using-a-wcf-client
You could also generate the client proxy class by SVCUtil tool.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-3.5/aa347733(v=vs.90)
I have made a simple demo, wish it is useful to you.
**Server:**

```
namespace Server8
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Uri uri = new Uri("http://localhost:1900");
            BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
            using (ServiceHost sh=new ServiceHost(typeof(MyService),uri))
            {
                sh.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService), binding, "");
                ServiceMetadataBehavior smb;
                smb = sh.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceMetadataBehavior>();
                if (smb==null)
                {
                    smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior()
                    {
                        HttpGetEnabled = true
                    };
                    sh.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);
                }
                Binding binding1 = MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexHttpBinding();
                sh.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMetadataExchange), binding1, "mex");
                sh.Open();
                Console.WriteLine("Service is ready...");

                Console.ReadLine();
                sh.Close();
            }

        }
    }
    [ServiceContract(Namespace ="mydomain")]
    public interface IService
    {
        [OperationContract(Name ="AddInt")]
        int Add(int x, int y);

    }
    public class MyService : IService
    {
        public int Add(int x, int y)
        {
            return x + y;
        }
    }
}
```

So the WSDL address is,

```
Http://localhost:1900?wsdl
```

**Svctutil Tool.**

```
Svcutil http://localhost:1900?wsdl /directory:D: /namespace:”mydomain”,”LocalProjectNamespace”
```

This command would generate a client proxy class in local D partition and replace the web service's namespace with "LocalProjectNamespace", it also generates a client configuration file(xml),which describes the service's binding and endpoint information.
[image]
And then we call the web service via client proxy class.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ServiceClient client = new ServiceClient();
    try
    {
        var result = client.AddInt(23, 55);
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: My main problem is with the local namespace. The scenario is: i'm dealing with gov service. They provided me a wsdl file, and they have a standard soap envelop which doens't care which "company" they are calling. That been said, they expect to call exactly the wsdl they provided me!

Comment: ex: their namespace `targetNamespace="http://com.xxx.update.ws"` and their soap body that they produce and expect me to handle looks like: `<soapenv:body><p820:methodName xmlns:p820="http://com.xxx.update.ws">`. Does that make it any easier to make my point :)?

Comment: sorry for my poor English. Is svcutil /Namespace parameter your want? it allows us to send the soap message with the server's namespace(we could check it in the soap message)

Comment: i just updated the question, i hope it makes it clearer